# Observable this scope is not working on call back function

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using observable for sharing the value from shared service to other components but when subscribing the value is coming as undefined. I have checked the observable and subscriber are working fine when I am not using any callback function but when I am setting "this" variable through a setter method within a callback function then the scope of this seems to get completed and the value of a subscriber is shown as Undefined...

shared/ExamplenService.ts

```
    @Injectable()
    export class ExamplenService {
    someValue: any;



      public seturl(someUrl:String){
     this.url=someUrl;
       });


       public seturl(){

       var that=this;
       return  return Observable.create(observer => {
      cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
      onSuccess: function (result) {
      // Some code

    getOtherUrl:function(err, data){ // Call back
     console.log("Checkdata"+data.url);// I can see the value here
      that.seturl(data.url) // The value is getting set here

        }

       });


    public getSomething(): any {
    const studentsObservable = new Observable(observer => {
       setTimeout(() => {
           observer.next(this.sameValue);
       }, 1000);
    });

    return studentsObservable;
   }
```

dashboard/test/TestComponent.ts

```
  export class TestComponent implements OnInit
 _data : any;


constructor(private http: Http, private example: ExamplenService) {

 }

    ngOnInit() {
    const s= this.example.getSomething().subscribe((_url :String)=>
    {

      console.log("Rest1"+_url);//This log is  showing undefined)
     this._data =_url;
     console.log("Rest2"+this._data);//This log is  showing undefined)
   });
   }
```

Comment: stackblitz demo please!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but try this:

```
ngOnInit() {
  const s = this.example.getSomething().subscribe((_url: String) => {
    if (_url) {
      console.log("Rest1" + _url);
      this._data = _url;
      console.log("Rest2" + this._data);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: _url is coming as undefined... Anyway I tried not working.